# ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'

Tags: erc-20, truffle-compile, solidity-0.6.x

Can someone explain to me about this error? I just tried override feature in Solidity v0.6, but I got error `Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override' function totalSupply()  public override  view returns (uint256)` when compile contract.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";

    contract ERC20 is IERC20 {

    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    /**
    * @dev See `IERC20.totalSupply`.
    */
    function totalSupply()  public override  view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    } 
}
```

Interface contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

interface IERC20 {
        /**
         * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
         */
        function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
}
```

Comment: I would guess that you need to declare function `totalSupply` in interface `IERC20` as `virtual`.

Comment: Also, note that your overriding function should probably be `external` instead of `public`.

Comment: thanks @goodvibration, i have tried both solution, but still return same error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed few '}' at the end of your contract and interface. the following works perfectly :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract ERC20 is IERC20 {

mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

uint256 private _totalSupply;

/**
* @dev See `IERC20.totalSupply`.
*/
function totalSupply()  public override  view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I intentionally didn't attach all the codes. But now I try to only use 1 function on the interface and 1 override function like your solution and still return same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it setting the Solidity compiler version to **0.6.8** (the latest at the current moment).

This can be done on Remix in the Compiler section, or in Truffle editing the file truffle-config.js.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to solidity version.
change the version to -

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

also in truffle config, change the solidity version.

```
solc: "^0.8.0"
```

Now, first update your truffle using :

```
npm i -g truffle
```

Now try to compile your code:

```
truffle compile
```

It will successfully compile....